# Intel Wireless AC-8260 wifi unstable

Tags: networking, drivers

I would like to ask a question regarding this wireless controller. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Latitude E5470 and I have connectivity and stability issues. I have a UPC Connect Box router whither I would like to connect but unfortunately it does not work. To be a bit more specific:

I can connect to my 802.11ac/5ghz network for the first time without any problem but then if I disconnect from the network/suspend my laptop/reboot I cannot connect again moreover (since I use dual boot with Windows 10) I can confirm that my bandwidth drops from 120 Mbit to around 2-3 Mbit under Windows, then just resetting the router helps.

It seems like if my WLAN adapter sends too many or maybe not standard packets, but I am not sure. Under lspci I can see the device, then iwconfig neither shows me anything suspicious. (I can attach these outputs later).

I know it is not the clearest explanation but I would appreciate any help which brings me closer to debug this phenomena.

**UPDATE:**

[Output of wireless info script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23106458/)

It seems to be running great after I fine-tuned my firewall configuration, but feel free to check - and I would like to to ask you - my log and notify if there is a misconfiguration or something like that :)

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos. Also, if the problem occurs across different OSs, the device itself may be defective.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thank you for your suggestion! I will update my question tomorrow. :)

Comment: @mikewhatever Question updated :)